# Вставка данных в таблицу PostgresSQL заканчивается ошибкой

Tags: postgresql, триггер

Разбераюсь с триггерными функциями.
Для этого сначала была создана простая табличка и добавлена функция:

```
CREATE TABLE AplusB (A integer, B integer);
INSERT INTO AplusB VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO AplusB VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO AplusB VALUES (3,3);
CREATE FUNCTION plus(integer, integer) RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE SQL AS 'SELECT $1 + $2;';
```

После создана ещё одна табличка и триггерная функция:

```
CREATE TABLE ABresult (result integer);
CREATE FUNCTION ABsumm() returns TRIGGER AS
'BEGIN
DELETE FROM ABresult;
INSERT INTO ABresult VALUES (AplusB.A+AplusB.B);
RETURN NULL;
END;'
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
CREATE TRIGGER makeABresult
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON AplusB
FOR EACH STATEMENT execute procedure ABsumm();
```

После попытки вставки:

```
INSERT INTO AplusB VALUES (100,200);
```

Возникает ошибка:

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "aplusb"
>   СТРОКА 1:INSERT INTO ABresult VALUES (AplusB.A+AplusB.B)
>   ^
>   ЗАПРОС: INSERT INTO ABresult VALUES (AplusB.A+AplusB.B)
>   КОНТЕКСТ: PL/pgSQL function "absumm" line 3 at SQL statement

В чём может быть проблема?

(Источник примеров: wiki.linuxformat.ru/wiki/LXF87-88:PostgreSQL)

Comment: PostgreSQL понятия не имеет, как найти `AplusB.A+AplusB.B`, потому что у вас в запросе не фигурирует `AplusB`.

Comment: Как не фигурирует? Указываю же в какую таблицу: INSERT INTO AplusB VALUES (100,200)

Comment: и что такое AplusB.A?

Answer (score 1):

Дело, вероятно, в том, что Postgres не может понять, что именно ему нужно сложить в функции на 3-ей строчке.
В триггер-функцию при её вызове передаётся некоторый контекст, в которому можно обращаться. В вашем случае, насколько я понимаю, вам нужно получить значения, от вставки/обновления которых сработал триггер.

Если так, то попробуйте заменить в функции:

`INSERT INTO ABresult VALUES (AplusB.A+AplusB.B);`

на:

`INSERT INTO ABresult VALUES (NEW.A + NEW.B);`

Более детальную информацию по поводу контекста можно получить [здесь](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Comment: Помагла замена                                                                                `INSERT INTO ABresult VALUES AplusB.A+AplusB.B);`    на          `INSERT INTO ABresult ( result ) SELECT A + B FROM AplusB;`